# UIMenucontroller placement issue in WkWebview

Tags: ios, wkwebview, uimenucontroller

I am working on UIMenuController in WKWebView.
My requirement is like open UIMenucontroller from UIMenucontroller.

Below is the scenario steps.

1. First wkwebview is launch in my application.
2. Then I select text from that webiview.
3. After selecting text in webview multiple options are visible in menuContorller like copy, copyWithReferencd and my custom menu options etc...
4. From that menuController I clicked on one of the menu item.
5. Now I have to open another menuController having different options.
6. In my case menuController open properly but placement of menuController is not proper. Also I don't have rect where to display 2nd menuController.

So, I am stuck that how to open 2nd menuController at proper place.

- I tried all properties in UIMenuController but it didn't worked for me.
- I made menuController nil after selecting first menu action. Then also not worked.

Expected result:

- Second menucontroller should open at proper place with proper arrow direction.

Answer (score 0):

Create Table View controller and Manager one dictionary for Menu option hierarchy. If you select one option from Parent Menu then reload that tableview with child option of menu and Display one back icon on Top Left corner for Navigation between parent and child menu. That way you can manage it.